# Get Group ID from Power BI embed URL

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-api

I'm trying to embed an existing Power BI Report within our application. From my understanding, the process to do that is as follows...

1. Given an embed url, something like...

```
https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=xxx&autoAuth=true&ctid=xxx
```

2. Obtain groupId (workspaceId) of report ❓❓❓
3. Generate embed token through the Power BI API

```
POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/${groupId}/reports/${reportId}/GenerateToken
```

Our API then returns the token back to the client and the token is used by the `powerbi-client` sdk to show the report. I'm purposefully simplifying how to display the report in the UI as it's not applicable for my issue.

**My question is**... given the embed url of a report `https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=xxx&autoAuth=true&ctid=xxx`, how can I obtain the groupId of that report so I can generate an embed token?

Or perhaps there's a better way to go about obtaining the embed token for an embed URL altogether. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: PBI Service? What do you mean by service? I have an embed url with the reportId and the clientId (tenantId), that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out so I'll answer my own question in case anyone else has a similar issue.

#### 1. [Get a list of reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/reports-get-reports-as-admin)

`myorg/admin/reports` returns the reports available to the tenant. The [response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/reports-get-reports-as-admin#adminreport) provides the workspace ID for each report.

**Find the correct report**

```js
const report = response.value.find((r) => r.id === reportId)
```

The accessing service principal or user will need `Tenant.Read.All` or `Tenant.ReadWrite.All`. Additionally, there are some caveats on permissions when accessing this endpoint. Please see the [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/reports-get-reports-as-admin) of this endpoint for additional information.

> The user must have administrator rights (such as Office 365 Global Administrator or Power BI Service Administrator) or authenticate using a service principal.
> Delegated permissions are supported. 
> When running under service prinicipal authentication, an app must not have any admin-consent required premissions for Power BI set on it in the Azure portal.

#### 2. Request Embed Token

Now that I have the workspace ID for the given report, I can make a request for an embed token that's valid only for that report.

```
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/${report.workspaceId}/reports/${reportId}/GenerateToken
```